# How to find cpu usage as shown in taskmanager using performance monitor

Tags: windows, cpu, performance, task-manager, performance-monitor

I want to know the CPU usage of a process(given its PID) as shown in the task manager, using performance monitor, as I have to benchmark the performance of the process. [This page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0435e7c5-3cda-41a0-953e-7fa462fde03b/perfmon-process-processor-time-vs-task-manager8217s-cpu-usage-for-monitoring-a-specific?forum=perfmon) shows that `%Processor Time` shown in performance monitor is not the same as CPU utilisation shown in task manager. But the alternative approaches mentioned there are also not matching with the taskmngr's value.
Is there any way to find the value shown in the task manager from performance monitor?
Below is a screenshot of the process's values in taskmngr and performance monitor:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can anyone make sense of the values in the performance monitor with the cpu utilisation in taskmanager?

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the performance monitor but with task manager itself!! Task manager was showing different cpu usage values in `Processes` tab and in `Details` tab. `%Processor Time` of the process when divided by number of processors  and rounded to nearest integer is actually matching with the value in the `Details` tab